# Symbol 'type cats.MonadFilter' is missing fromthe classpath

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monix

I am reading this tutorial on [tagless final](https://www.beyondthelines.net/programming/introduction-to-tagless-final/).

Based on this I have defined my dependencies as

```
object Dependencies {
  lazy val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
  lazy val cats = "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.2.0"
  lazy val monix = "io.monix" %% "monix" % "2.3.3"
  lazy val monixCats = "io.monix" %% "monix-cats" % "2.3.3"
}
```

The following is my code

```
// future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

// cats
import cats.Monad
import cats.implicits._

// monix
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.cats._
import monix.cats.reverse._


trait ProductRepository[M[_]] {
  def findProduct(productId: ProductId) : M[Option[Product]]
  def saveProduct(product: Product) : M[Unit]
  def incrementProductSales(productId: ProductId, quantity: Long) : M[Unit]
}

class ProductRepositoryWithFuture extends ProductRepository[Future] {
  def findProduct(productId: ProductId) : Future[Option[Product]] = {
    Future.successful(Some(Product(productId, "foo")))
  }
  def saveProduct(product: Product) : Future[Unit] = {
    Future.successful()
  }
  def incrementProductSales(productId: ProductId, quanity: Long) : Future[Unit] = {
    Future.successful()
  }
}

class ProductRepositoryWithTask extends ProductRepository[Task] {
  def findProduct(productId: ProductId) : Task[Option[Product]] = {
    Task.now(Some(Product(productId, "foo")))
  }
  def saveProduct(product: Product) : Task[Unit] = {
    Task.unit
  }
  def incrementProductSales(productId: ProductId, quantity: Long) : Task[Unit] = {
    Task.unit
  }
}
```

But I get bunch of errors. It seems that the version of cats which I am using is not compatible with the one Monix uses.

I also tried to remove my cats dependency and just imported monix so that monix pulls in its own version of cats. but even that doesn't compile.

```
error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:54:24: Symbol 'type cats.MonadFilter' is missing fromthe classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'method monix.cats.MonixToCatsCore7.monixToCatsMonadFilter'.
[error] Make sure that type MonadFilter is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'MonixToCatsCore7.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of cats.
[error]       repo.findProduct(id).flatMap{
[error]                        ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:54:23: diverging implicit expansion for type monix.types.Comonad[M]
[error] starting with method catsToMonixComonad in trait CatsCoreToMonix5
[error]       repo.findProduct(id).flatMap{
[error]                       ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:54:28: value flatMap is not a member of type parameter M[Option[example.Application.Product]]
[error]       repo.findProduct(id).flatMap{
[error]                            ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:56:30: value copy is not a member of Any
[error]           val newProduct = p.copy(name = name)
[error]                              ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:56:40: reassignment to val
[error]           val newProduct = p.copy(name = name)
[error]                                        ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:57:27: diverging implicit expansion for type monix.types.MonadError[M,E]
[error] starting with method catsToMonixMonadError in trait CatsCoreToMonix3
[error]           repo.saveProduct(newProduct).map(_ => Some(p))
[error]                           ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:57:40: value map is not a member of type parameter M[Unit]
[error]           repo.saveProduct(newProduct).map(_ => Some(p))
[error]                                        ^
[error] /Users/foobar/code/tagless/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:59:16: diverging implicit expansion for type cats.Comonad[M]
[error] starting with method monixToCatsComonad in trait MonixToCatsCore5
[error]           Monad[M].pure(None)
[error]                ^
[error] 8 errors found
```

Comment: Full code. https://github.com/abhsrivastava/tagless. Just in case if anyone needs it.

Comment: I am seeing a similar error with your set of dependencies and I get a pass if I upgrade to these dependencies:      libraryDependencies += "io.monix" %% "monix" % "3.0.0-RC1"  and  libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.2.0"
. But I am curious what it takes to make it work in version 2, so I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I couldn't fix it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The errors are caused by incompatibilities between your dependencies.
For example monix `2.3.3` depends on cats `0.9.0` while you're trying to use `1.2.0` which is binary incompatible.

You should try either upgrading `monix` to `3.x` or downgrading `cats` to `0.9.0`.

P.S. The transition from cats `0.9.0` to `1.x` has a lot of breaking [changes](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/CHANGES.md#to-migrate-from-090) and you have to make sure that all libraries you're using are compiled against the same (or at least binary compatible) version of cats.